# Drives fail on one PC setup, but works flawlessly on another

Tags: hard-drive, raid, motherboard

I've been using two drives in RAID0 for a while and recently switched to a new PC setup. It worked as it should at the beginning but after a reboot a few months ago I noticed that one of the drives started to make some kind of noise: a short beep followed by a spin-up.

Checking the logs, as well as start up output, I saw that the noise was followed by a few lines of error codes. The server however came up, but made that beep noise a few times a day. Untill yesterday, when both drives started acting like this, making the noise, creating the output below. I could no longer get the server back up.

Today I put together the old PC build and plugged the drives in - no issues at all. Also other drives that also works as they should in other computers acts like these two in the RAID as well. Why is that?

So the question here is: Why does my drive work on the old setup but not on the new? (I've used the drives on both system but when I switched to the new setup I did a complete re-install of Ubuntu server 16.04.1 LTS)

The drive is, as I said, in (software) RAID0, but also a LVM LUKS group on that RAID.

I believe there's something about the motherboard doing this so here they are:

- Old build: MSI P35 Platinum
- New build: ASUS M5A99FX PRO R2.0

Both motherboards has the latest BIOS update.

Here's and image of the output - I had to take a picture using my phone.
[image]

Comment: It also could be a power issue.  Perhaps the disks don't get enough power to spin up correctly (spinup uses the most power)

Comment: Ah, I see. So possibly the PSU(?). I'll see if another will make a difference. Also replace the GPU since the one in the new build is rather power "needy".

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I replaced the PSU and it works flawlessly! :D

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the PSU and now it works great again.